# May the path be unrelated to the name of a file in WebDAV

Tags: .net, webdav

I'm using the .NET-Server from IT-Hits WebDAV implementation and couldn't figure out my question from the documentation.

The WebDAVEngine uses a class called `IHierarchyItem` wich has the Properties `Path` and `Name`.
So my question: Has the path be directly related to the items name? So if path is /folder/file.txt has the name to be file.txt or can i provide a generic name? So if the path would be /abc.txt may the name be something else? Or does this affect the Clients?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I havent used that specific webdav server, but I know that for webdav generally there is a display-name property which is independent of the resource href.

BUT this property **IS NOT USED** by most webdav clients. Instead webdav clients generally just use the last path segment as the file name and ignore the display-name property.

Answer (score 1):

Most WebDAV clients including Microsoft Mini-redirector and Microsoft Office ignore the dispaly-name property, (which is behind the [IHierarchyItem.Name](http://doc3.webdavsystem.com/ITHit.WebDAV.Server.IHierarchyItem.Name.html)). However I have seen WebDAV clients that utilize dispaly-name, if it is missing, empty or corrupted such clients do not function properly.

To avoid confusion and to support maximum number of WebDAV clients I would suggest always keeping IHierarchyItem.Name and IHierarchyItem.Path in sync. For example if IHierarchyItem.Path returns 'folder/file.txt', the IHierarchyItem.Name must return 'file.txt'